# MongoDB Multi Master in different region

Tags: mongodb

I'm totally stuck. I have two applications in two different zones. These two applications are using MongoDB. I want to run these two MongoDBs as master/master.

I have installed 2 shards, but both of them are working as a primary. I am open to your ideas and suggestions on this matter.

Comment: A sharded cluster requires at least 3 nodes. I assume you mixed up something.

Comment: I have configured 3 config, 1 mongos, 2 sharding(2 primary + 4 secondary) instances. They are using different sharding. shard01 and shard02

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to run these two MongoDBs as master/master."?

Comment: yes, correct. It s not possible ?

Comment: As said, I have no idea what you mean. A sharded cluster is **one** database, of course you can use one database by several applications. And what do you mean by "They are using different sharding."?

Comment: Actually, I just want to configure mongodb master/master. One master is located in Usa, another master is located in HongKong. So I just need a master/master replication.

Comment: That's not possible. MongoDB supports only Replica Set with **exactly one** PRIMARY and one or many **SECONDARY**. You can connect to a SECONDARY if you like, however then you can just read. You can write only into PRIMARY - no exception!

Comment: Maybe have a look at [Segmenting Data by Location](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/sharding-segmenting-data-by-location/) Should be exactly what you are looking for. However, I would suggest to create also two `mongos`, one for each region. Maybe you mixed terms "sharding" and "replication"

Comment: When I asked this before, they said you can do it with sharding. :|